# Ssh connection refused

Tags: raspbian, ssh

My raspberry pi randomly started refusing connections. After a reboot it allows connections, nothing has been changed in months with the config.

Here is the `ssh -vvv` output

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.3, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.21 [192.168.1.21] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/matthew/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/matthew/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/matthew/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/matthew/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/matthew/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/matthew/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/matthew/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

output of `stat /home/matthew/.ssh/id_rsa`

```
  File: ‘/home/matthew/.ssh/id_rsa’  
  Size: 1675            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file    
Device: 811h/2065d      Inode: 564404    Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: ( 1000/ matthew)   Gid: ( 1000/ matthew)
Access: 2015-10-26 20:46:38.000000000 -0400
Modify: 2011-03-06 22:34:36.000000000 -0500
Change: 2011-03-06 22:34:36.000000000 -0500   
 Birth: -
```

output of `stat /home/matthew/.ssh`

```
  File: ‘/home/matthew/.ssh’  
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory      
Device: 811h/2065d      Inode: 564461      Links: 2
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: ( 1000/ matthew)   Gid: ( 1000/ matthew)
Access: 2015-10-27 11:14:03.000000000 -0400
Modify: 2015-09-04 11:55:54.000000000 -0400
Change: 2015-09-04 11:55:54.000000000 -0400 
 Birth: -
```

**UPDATE**

I found last night that `ssh` began refusing new connections while I had an active/functioning connection on going. I tried to open another `ssh` connection and it again was refused.

Comment: do you have enough memory? Space on card? It used to happen to me also but now I have really long uptime.

Comment: I have 10+GB free

Comment: Does `/home/matthew/.ssh/id_rsa` exist?  Edit in the output from `stat /home/matthew/.ssh/id_rsa` and `stat /home/matthew/.ssh`.

Comment: Added the requested outputs

Comment: Do you connect with the right username. e.g. `ssh pi@192.168.1.21`. If you connect with `ssh 192.168.1.21` without a username then, a user matthew must exist on the raspi. The public key is taken from that user account. Perhaps you connect with a existing username when it worked and without a username when it refused connection. It's just a guess ;-).

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer Yes same username on both, I've also tried adding the matthew@ just in case it would work and it does not change the results

Comment: Do you connect from linux, windows, OSX? Are you sure the firewall does not block under certain conditions? Do you have multiple private rsa files in your desktop computers .ssh directory? If so have you added the public key of all of them to your authorized_keys file on the pi? If on windows have you started pageant and added your private key? If all failes: Can you uninstall open_ssh on your pi and reinstall it again; or reconfigure it with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ssh` if you have a debian on the pi (e.g. raspbian). After the next fail try `dmesg` and check the output for related hints.

Comment: Ah, and don't forget to update the source index before reinstalling ssh. On debian `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer Windows (putty), Linux, and Android (juicessh). All are refused. Firewall is not the issue, as it works for connections inside and outside of the firewall. I've done a reconfigure, still no change. I've also relocated my entire .ssh folder to .ssh2 on both my Debian server and the pi and it still starts refusing.

Comment: Did you create a new .ssh on each device with your private key id_rsa file on debian and an authorized_keys file on the raspi containing the public key after relocating? Another idea: Have you accidently another device with adress 192.168.1.21 in your network. That'd explain that weird behavior and also why it works again after a reboot of your pi. Next time it refuses connect, try `arp -n`   on you debian box and check if the ip adress 192.168.1.21 is mapped with the correct MAC adress of you pi. Or try an `nmap 192.168.1.1-255` on your debian box. Probably you have to install nmap before.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer yes i recreated .ssh with the new keys. And arp -n reports the correct MAC. Also other connections to the pi are aloud such as the web traffic, and webiopi traffic.

Comment: Sorry then I have no more good ideas. Perhaps: If possible you can create a new SD card with a new Raspian (Wheezy) installation. If the misbehavior remains then you have likely a problem with your ssh-clients (Putty, ...) or the network configuration. If it disappears I would say something went wrong on your pi resp. the old sd card. Perhaps a virus, unawared misconfiguration, the kernel firewall of your pi. Perhaps before you install a new SD card; you can change your ip adress with the last number from 21 to e.g. 42 (if it still free) and try if the error depend on the ip adress.

Answer (score 1):

So I believe I found the culprit. I don't know why it had any effect on eth0 but when I used to have my pi connected via WiFi I had this script running.

```
while true ; do
    if ifconfig wlan0 | grep -q "inet addr:" ; then
        sleep 60
    else
        echo "Network connection down! Attempting reconnection."
        ifup --force wlan0
        sleep 10
    fi
    done
```

This resolved some dropped WiFi issues. I'm not sure why all of a sudden it started causing refused ssh connections, after almost a year of using the hard wired connection. But its been chugging along all day now and has not refused a single connection.

Comment: 14 hours later, and still working with this fix.

Answer (score 0):

Possible fix:

Remove your `~/.ssh` folder, this will reset all of ssh's settings.

`sudo rm -Rf ~/.ssh`

Comment: This did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what does "randomly" mean?

1. It works after reboot for a while, and then it stops working forever

OR

2. After a while it sometimes works, sometimes does not.

I would check:

- is `sshd` running? `$ ps aux | grep -i sshd`
- what happens if you start / restart `sshd`?  `$ sudo service ssh start` and/or `$ sudo service ssh restart`
- any significant entries in the following logs: `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/auth.log` that correlate to the connection failures ?

Comment: Random as in it works after reboot, then at some random time begins refusing connections until next reboot, sshd is running, no errors reported in auth.log or syslog. Auth.log does not even show the attempted login. Restarting ssh does not change anything as well

Comment: Could it be that there is some networking issue e.g. Raspberry Pi disconnects or changes the IP address after a while? E.g. when you have the failure to connect to sshd, can you connect to something else on the Pi? Can you ping the Pi?

Comment: Webserver on the pi works, when ssh doesn't. Pi is hardwired to the router with static IP configured on both the pi and my router.